# Header function won't redirect, when i use curl to get redirect url

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

Question is better illustrated in code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://google.com';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
$result_header = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header('Location '.$result_header['redirect_uri']);//Here regional version of google, in my case its http://google.ru. 
?>
```

So header won't work. How to solve this problem?
Thanks.
Best regards Albina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two errors in your code:

- It should be `redirect_url`, with an `l`, not an `i`
- The colon after the header name is missing

Correct it should be

```
header('Location: '.$result_header['redirect_url']);
```

Comment: I rechecked and yeah you right, i confused with OAuth protocol before so use redirect_uri instead of redirect_url. OAuth use redirect_uri as token. Thank you.